# Difficulty importing @opentok/client library dynamically in React.Js, facing TypeScript error

Tags: typescript, opentok, dynamic-import, react-lazy-load

`import OT, {`
`Device, Publisher, Session, SubscriberProperties`
`} from '@opentok/client';`

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to
`import the @opentok/client` library dynamically in a React application to reduce bundle size. Here's the code I'm using:

`const OT = React.lazy(() => import('@opentok/client'));`
I am importing this into context provider. But facing this typescript error

`Type 'Promise<{ default: typeof OT;` `checkScreenSharingCapability(callback: (response:` `ScreenSharingCapabilityResponse) => void): void;` `checkSystemRequirements(): number; ... 25 more ...; Subscriber:` `typeof Subscriber; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<{` `default: ComponentType<any>; }>'.`
`Type '{ default: typeof OT;` `checkScreenSharingCapability(callback: (response:` `ScreenSharingCapabilityResponse) => void): void;` `checkSystemRequirements(): number; ... 25 more ...; Subscriber:` `typeof Subscriber; }' is not assignable to type` `'{` `default:` `ComponentType<any>; }'.`
`Types of property 'default' are incompatible.`
`Type 'typeof OT' is not assignable to type` `'ComponentType<any>'.ts(2322)`

Can we import library dynamically in react.js?